# How to codedeploy appspec.yml runas ubuntu user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

AWS CodeDeploy is used for a simple WordPress application. Installed AWS codedeploy-agent on ubuntu 20.04 with help of the below script

```
#!/bin/bash
apt update
apt install ruby -y
gem install bundler
git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent.git /opt/codedeploy-agent
sudo chown -R root.root /opt/codedeploy-agent
sudo chmod 644 /opt/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
sudo chmod 755 /opt/codedeploy-agent/init.d/codedeploy-agent
sudo chmod 644 /opt/codedeploy-agent/init.d/codedeploy-agent.service
cd /opt/codedeploy-agent
bundle install --system
rake clean && rake
cp /opt/codedeploy-agent/init.d/codedeploy-agent /etc/init.d/
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start codedeploy-agent
systemctl enable codedeploy-agent
```

Using the below appspec.yml for code deployment. Its working fine with `runas root`

**Questions :**

1. How to run it as an `ubuntu` user, ?
2. Is any issue with while running as `root` user ?
   ....

appspec.yaml file

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html/
    overwrite: true
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/before_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/setup_environment.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root 
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 900
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      timeout: 300
  ValidateService:
    - location: scripts/validate_service.sh
      timeout: 300
```

While runas ubuntu getting the below error.

```
Error code
ScriptFailed
Script name
scripts/setup_environment.sh
Message
Script at specified location: scripts/setup_environment.sh run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 4



LifecycleEvent - AfterInstall
Script - scripts/setup_environment.sh
[stderr]shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
[stderr]shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
[stderr]/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/44d6390b-485e-87ef-b50855bbf251/d-D0RTN7AR5/deployment-archive/scripts/setup_environment.sh: line 4: /var/www/html/.env: Permission denied
[stderr]sed: couldn't open temporary file /var/www/html/scripts/seTwGZAv: Permission denied
```

Comment: I don't understand the exact question. Are you asking how to run script with user other than root? or are you asking if there would be any issues while running script as root user.

Comment: Both are my concerns, How to run the script with other than root and is any issue with running it as root

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and post edit. I have added an answer that might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it as `ubuntu` user it will not work due to **lack of permissions** which you are experiencing:

```
couldn't open temporary file /var/www/html/scripts/seTwGZAv: Permission denied
```

The reason is that `/var/www/html/` is not accessible by `ubuntu` user. To make it work you would have to change its default permissions which is a **bad practice**.

Some things have to be executed as `root`, unless you want to start changing default configurations and permission model of `ubuntu` operating system.

Answer (score 0):

As appspec.yml file and scripts are managed by you, there is not any security issue while running our script as root. What you'll write is what you'll get.

While using any non root user it is important to provide all the required permissions to that user. In most of the cases you will have to use `sudo` before each command and make sure your user is [added to sudoers](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-user-to-sudoers-in-ubuntu/).

You need to make sure that

1. Your git is secure from any unauthorized changes.
2. CodeDeploy is only accessible to the trusted resources.

If these two things are checked, there's no way any anomalous command can run on your system

Comment: Thanks for your update. I've only concern about the running as the root user, like any security breach,

Comment: @bibincatchme, that's a valid concern, but there's no security breach expected. You need to make sure that 1 - your git is secure from any unauthorized changes. 2- CodeDeploy is only accessible to the trusted resources. If these two things are checked there's no way any anomalous command can run on your system.